# How can I find entries in elastic where a specific value is present in array?

Tags: elasticsearch

Ok, this is the schema:

```
id
generated{
    status{
        myStatuses[]
    }
}
```

So having now these entries:

```
id=1
generated.status.myStatuses=['busy', 'free']
id=2
generated.status.myStatuses=['busy']
id=3
generated.status.myStatuses=['free']
```

I want to match all the documents where "generated.status.myStatuses" contains the word "free".
In the example above I would find id=1 and id=3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no [dedicated array datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) in ES so you can treat your keyword arrays as keywords. This means either

```
GET generated/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "generated.status.myStatuses": "free"
    }
  }
}
```

or, for exact matches,

```
GET generated/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "generated.status.myStatuses.keyword": "free"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
         "generated.status.myStatuses":"free"
    } 
  }
}
```

You need to use `match` or `term` queries based on your data mapping.